# Force closing shared file: NetFileClose

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm trying to make a program that force the connection to a shared file. I found the system call **NetFileClose** and it seems to be very simple; but when I call it, it retourned me always the error code number 53. 
Like parameter I give servername NULL (I try also with 0 but with the same result) and fileid a correct value.
I logged in with an administrator user.

Definition:

```
function NetFileClose(servername : LPSTR; fileid: DWORD) : NET_API_STATUS;

implementation

const
  netapi32 = 'Netapi32.dll';

function NetFileClose; external netapi32 name 'NetFileClose';
```

Comment: `SysErrorMessage(53)` returns "The network path cannot be found" (free translation from Swedish).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=44950&tstart=0) at EDN, you need to add stdcall to the definition.